How to enable dhcp-option domain search for openvpn-as?
I’m using OpenVPN Access Server (openvpn-as) as my custom VPN solution, with the following configuration (json):
(...)
"vpn.server.dhcp_option.dns.0": "172.27.0.2",
"vpn.server.dhcp_option.dns.1": "8.8.8.8",
"vpn.server.dhcp_option.domain": "ops.company.com,services.company.com",
(...)

This setup works perfectly for resolving queries like ping machine-a.ops.company.com. However, I want to simplify this and resolve queries by just specifying the hostname, like ping machine-a, without explicitly including the domain name.
From their docs, I see that OpenVPN supports the DOMAIN-SEARCH option. Based on this, I attempted to configure:
vpn.server.dhcp_option.domain-search": "ops.company.com,services.company.com",

Unfortunately, this configuration didn’t work as expected, and queries for just machine-a still fail. I’m looking for a way to achieve this functionality.
